# Missing element SESSION_ID (LoginRequest.REQUEST_HEADER) on Python Zeep

Tags: python-3.x, invoice, zeep

I want to integrate an invoice api on python with zeep library. When I create Client object and send request with client.service.Login, Python is giving error Missing element SESSION_ID (LoginRequest.REQUEST_HEADER). I think the invoice api needs REQUEST_HEADER parameter with SESSION_ID in it. But how can i make it successfully. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import zeep
import requests

wsdl = 'URL'
client = zeep.Client(wsdl=wsdl)

client.service.Login('username','password')
```

```
ValidationError: Missing element SESSION_ID (LoginRequest.REQUEST_HEADER)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved the problem. I only created dictionary with `session_id` and then passed this dictionary as a parameter to the `Login` function:

```
import zeep
import requests

wsdl = 'URL'


client = zeep.Client(wsdl=wsdl)
data = {'SESSION_ID':'0'}

session_id = client.service.Login(data, 'username', 'password')
print(session_id)
```

Output:

```
'SESSION_ID': 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx.....',
'ERROR_TYPE': None
```